# add_post_meta -- not working

Tags: database, wpdb

I am trying to insert data into wp_post and wp_postmeta tables but it seems like i am doing something wrong.

Here is my code:

```
$post_data = array(
                                    'post_title' => $data[0],
                                    'post_content' => $data[1],
                                    'post_status' => 'publish',
                                    'post_type' => 'product'
                                );

                                $id = wp_insert_post($post_data);
                                add_post_meta($id, '_stock', $data[6]);
                                add_post_meta($id, '_price', $data[7]);
```

The post is inserted as it should but when i check the postmeta table no values had been inserted. I also tried the update_post_meta but still doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It should work. Turn WP_DEBUG on and check if there are any warnings or notices. You can also var_dump $id variable to check if it is post id and not WP_Error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What user34296 said is `update_post_meta()` will update the value of the existing meta key (custom field) for the specified post. If it does not already exist it will call `add_post_meta($post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value)` instead. That's why you should use it.

**EDIT: in this case it should work, error is coming from another part of the code.**

[Source](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta)

Answer (score 0):

you should try like this:

```
update_post_meta( $id, '_price', true );
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer: **why** could that solve the problem?

Comment: sorry,i'm not english man.just know it will work..